Return a list of entities instead of a list of dto's
I have this simple DTO class:
public class ActionDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}

And I have this mapping profile:
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
    public MappingProfiles() {
        CreateMap<ActionDTO, Models.Admin.Action>();
        CreateMap<Models.Admin.Action, ActionDTO>();
    }
}

The controller looks like this:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ActionDTO>>> GetActions()
{
    if (planProDbContext.Actions == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    IEnumerable<Models.Admin.Action> actions = await planProDbContext.Actions.ToListAsync();
    // List<ActionDTO> actionDTOs = mapper.Map<List<ActionDTO>>(actions);
    return Ok(actions);
}

As you see, I return actions, and not a list of dto's. But the signature of the method is Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ActionDTO>>>. Why does this work?

Not sure, how async-await is related to the issue.

It works because you are returning an OkObjectResult from the method and not an IEnumerable<Models.Admin.Action>. Result objects in ASP.NET inherit from ActionResult which is ultimately the return type of your method, and although it's not obvious, there exists an implicit conversion between ActionResult<TValue> and ActionResult.
If you want that type safety compilation error, return the IEnumerable<Models.Admin.Action> collection directly instead of wrapping it in a result object and you will start to see a compilation error due to type mismatch. If you'd like, you can even forgo having the ActionResult in the method signature at all and just return a collection or class.
